# A question on measures and associated probability measures.

Tags: probability-theory

Given a measure space $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},\mu)$, with $\mu$ being the measure,
we can build a probability measure with $P(B)=\frac{\mu(B)}{\mu(\Omega)}$ for every subset $B$ of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{F}$.

Is this the only probability measure that can be constructed with $\mu$? If yes, how can we be sure, or if not, could you give an example and conditions for the answer to be positive, please?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mu(\Omega)>0$ then every nonnegative measurable function $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ that satisfies $\int fd\mu=1$ induces a probability measure on $\mathbb F$ prescribed by: $$B\mapsto\int f1_Bd\mu=\int_Bfd\mu$$

Your construction is a special case of this construction. It only works if also  $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ and rolls out if the function $f$ is prescribed by: $$\omega\mapsto \mu(\Omega)^{-1}$$

Then we get probability measure that sends $B$ to: $$\int_B\mu(\Omega)^{-1}d\mu=\frac{\mu(B)}{\mu(\Omega)}$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm still learning this subject, so could you please elaborate more on some aspects? For example, $\int_Bfd\mu$ be a measure? Also, how can f go from $\omega$ to $ \mu(\Omega)^{-1}$? I'm not understanding the notation.

Also, This measure seems equivalent to mine or particular example of mine, when you define $f(\omega)=1/\mu(\Omega)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Actually $\int_Bfd\mu$ is not a measure, but the *map* $B\mapsto\int_Bfd\mu$ is a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition). It is not difficult (and a good exercise) to prove the defining properties. The measure prescribed by you in your question is a special case of the construction mentioned in my answer. It deals with a *constant* function. This function indeed takes value $\mu(\Omega)^{-1}$ for every $\omega$. Also see my edit.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks ;)